How to draw a rectangle with one side in matplotlib?
I want to draw a rectangle in matplotlib and I want only the top edge to show. I tried to draw a line on top of the rectangle to make it work, but I was not satisfied with the result. Here's my code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

LIM = 5


def configure_plot(lim: float, **kwargs) -> tuple[Figure, Axes]:
    fig: Figure
    ax: Axes
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(**kwargs)
    ax.axis("equal")
    ax.set_axis_off()
    ax.set_xlim(-lim, lim)
    ax.set_ylim(-lim, lim)

    fig.tight_layout()
    return fig, ax


def main() -> None:
    fig: Figure
    ax: Axes
    fig, ax = configure_plot(LIM)

    width = 8
    height = 3.5
    color = "tab:blue"
    rect = Rectangle(
        (-width / 2, -height),
        width,
        height,
        facecolor=color,
        alpha=0.8,
        linewidth=3,
    )
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.plot([-width / 2, width / 2], [0, 0], color=color)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This gives me this output:

It's almost the result I am looking for, but the line of the edge continues slightly beyond the rectangle's corners which makes it look worse in my opinion. I could play with the line end points to shorten it and make it fit, but this doesn't sound like an ideal solution. Is there a way to draw a rectangle and only one of its edges in matplotlib?

No, but you could simply set the linewidth to 0, as the face color and edge are matched.

You can set the CapStyle for the ax.plot line to butt (instead of the default, which is projecting). You can use the solid_capstyle kwarg for this.
To demonstrate, I increased the line width to make the differences more obvious:
solid_capstyle='projecting'
ax.plot([-width / 2, width / 2], [0, 0], color=color,
        solid_capstyle='projecting', linewidth=5)


solid_capstyle='butt'
ax.plot([-width / 2, width / 2], [0, 0], color=color,
        solid_capstyle='butt', linewidth=5)



You could use Polygons, depending on what you try to achieve it allows to add further edges easily by just extending the slice (coords[start:end])
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 8
height = 3.5
x,y = (-width / 2, -height/2)
coord = [
    [x, y],                 # bottom-left
    [x+width, y],           # bottom-right
    [x+width, y+height],    # top-right
    [x, y+height],          # top-left
]

polygon = Polygon(coord, closed=True, facecolor='r')
polygon2 = Polygon(coord[2:4], fc='none', ec='blue', lw=3)

ax.add_patch(polygon)
ax.add_patch(polygon2)

plt.axis('equal') 
plt.ylim(-5, 5)
plt.xlim(-5, 5)

plt.show()

Which results in this:

